# What is node_base_interface used for in ROS 2?

Tags: ros-humble, rosnode, pluginlib, action-client, subscribers

I am writing plugins using pluginlib and one of the initialization arguments are a node, like so:

```
  void initialize(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::WeakPtr & parent,
    const std::string & plugin_name);
```

This allows me to pass the node where the plugin is loaded INTO the plugin for creating subscribers, clients etc.

A difficulty I am facing is that sometimes the node is a LifeCycle Node and sometimes it is a standard rclcpp::Node. To go around this, I am thinking of re-defining my plugins to take in a node_base_interface so that I can still create clients or subscribers inside them.

My question is whether this is a viable strategy? Can this allow me to create clients inside plugins irrespective of the node type (since I am not passing in the node anymore)?

How and when do we use the function get_node_base_interface()?
Please do let me know. I need to make the plugins agnostic to what kind of node they are used in - lifecycle or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A limitation you'd hit is that the node base interface does not include the parameters, logging, services, ..., interfaces. You'd have to pass each in.

My recommendation is to instead template the `NodePtr` type so that it can accept any lifecycle, normal node, or future node variants as long as they implement the same node interfaces.